# Replace different classes on hover in child element

Tags: jquery

I want to replace (swap) whatever the class of an element may be with `.icon-popup` whenever I hover over a table row. On `mouseleave`, I want the initial class swapped back.

```
<table class="libraryResults">
    <tr>
        <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-doc-text" data-id="icon-doc-text">a</i></span>  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-video" data-id="icon-video">b</i></span>    
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-mic" data-id="icon-mic">c</i></span>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The only way I've half-managed to do this is long-winded and cumbersome:

```
$(".libraryResults tr").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-doc-text").attr('class', 'icon-popup');
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-popup").attr('class', 'icon-doc-text');
});

$(".libraryResults tr").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-video").attr('class', 'icon-popup');
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-popup").attr('class', 'icon-video');
});

$(".libraryResults tr").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-mic").attr('class', 'icon-popup');
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".icon-popup").attr('class', 'icon-mic');
});
```

And of course it doesn't fully work. On `mouseleave` all classes are replaced by the first return function's class `.icon-doc-text`.

Any clues?

UPDATE 01: I think I may have to store its previous class so I can replace the .icon-popup on mouseleave with whatever it had prior to mouseenter.

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/snerone/5nc3P/)

UPDATE 02: Better still I could use data-attributes and `.data()` to retrieve the original class name for `mouseleave`

Comment: May you create a fiddle for that?

Comment: why $(".libraryResults tr") three times..??

Comment: @DipeshParmar I was being lazy and trying to get it to work.

Comment: @deadlock [Fiddle added](http://jsfiddle.net/snerone/5nc3P/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much shorter using [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and combining your additional requirements into a single selector, similar to this:

```
$(".libraryResults tr td").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".icon-doc-text, .icon-video, .icon-mic").toggleClass("icon-popup");
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufNkX/) - Using combined selector and `toggleClass`

---

or if you want the whole `td` to be effected use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in addition, similar to this:

```
$(".libraryResults tr td").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".icon-doc-text, .icon-video, .icon-mic").closest("td").toggleClass("icon-popup");
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JYqSP/) - Using `closest()` to apply to complete `td` element

---

This could be further improved if you either assign a single class to all `i` or `td` elements you wish to be effected. That way you can write something similar to this:

```
// If class 'myClass' is on all td elements
$(".libraryResults td.myClass").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-popup");
});
```

#### Edit

> But, I need to replace / swap the classes on hover and then swap them
>   back.

If you can influence the HTML then through the use of a `data-attribute` you can write a nice short-hand solution. As the `class` attribute can have multiple classes specified you could add a data attribute specifying the class you want to swap out-in and use that, similar to this:

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-doc-text" data-class-name="icon-doc-text">icon text</i></span>

    </td>
    <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-video" data-class-name="icon-video">icon video</i></span>

    </td>
    <td class="libFormat"> <span><i class="icon-mic" data-class-name="icon-mic">icon mic</i></span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Script

```
$(".libraryResults tr td").hover(function () {
    var $match = $(this).find("[data-class-name]");
    var className = $match.attr("data-class-name");

    $match.removeClass(className);
    $match.addClass("icon-popup");
}, function () {
    var $match = $(this).find("[data-class-name]");
    var className = $match.attr("data-class-name");

    $match.addClass(className);
    $match.removeClass("icon-popup");
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgLLp/) - Using the data attribute to specify the class to switch with

---

This is also quite extendable as you can add several space-separated classes to the data attribute and it still should works.

Comment: Nice try, thanks! But, I need to replace / swap the classes on hover and then swap them back. Toggle will only append the hover state class. Hence my use of attr.

Comment: @Seb: Ah, I see. I updated the answer with a nice short piece of code which still uses a single method for all, assuming you can add a data attribute. The `find` calls inside each function are cheap as they are scoped traversals so no worries there. The variables are both within their own function scope so they won't clash either. Hope this helps.